# How do I notify the IRS of a new member to an LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, irs

I started an LLC in NY but now I need to add a new member. I have been looking online and it claims I must notify the IRS however I cannot seem to find the appropriate links/forms that will let me notify them. Could someone offer some guidance as to how I can approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to notify the IRS of new members, the IRS doesn't care (at this stage).

What you do need, if you have a EIN for a single-member LLC, is [to request a **new** EIN](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Apply-for-an-Employer-Identification-Number-%28EIN%29-Online) since your LLC is now a partnership (a different entity, from IRS perspective).

From now on, you'll need to file form 1065 with the IRS in case of business related income, on which you will declare the membership distribution interests on Schedules K-1 for each member.